# fopen() Permission Denied despite having correct file directory

Tags: php

```
$handle = fopen('/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test/file.txt', 'w');
```

I tried doing the above and every time I try it, the following statement appeared on my browser:

> Warning:fopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test/file.txt)
>   [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test/index.php on line 26.

I tried looking through answered questions with the same type of questions but most of the things I tried did not work. For example, writing the full directory...

Comment: Does the web server have the appropriate permissions to descend to that path and write a file there, overwriting any that may already exist?

Comment: Are you in Linux ? Is the `chmod` of the file `777` ? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod

Comment: I am new to PHP and I don't know how to grant or take away access from the server accessing any directories. However, I haven't tinkered with any of the files from when I installed XAMPP on my computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe, you have no premissions to acces the file. One of the answet, is that, you must change `CHMOD` to e.g. `777`. You can co it with your ftp explorer or with PHP.

```
chmod("/somedir/somefile", 777);
```

Comment: After testing, it the following Warning appeared:Warning: chmod() [function.chmod]: Operation not permitted in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test/index.php on line 27

Comment: Before opening. Maybe, you are not administrator on the server where php is running.

Comment: How do I become the administrator? Sorry I'm a newby!

Comment: I really do not know on which web hosting are you, maybe try logging into your PHP Admin and find something useful.

Comment: I am on localhost. I figured out the problem. As you said, I was not the administrator of the server. Changing the chmod to 777 did the job!

Comment: 777 permission are wide open and insecure. It should only be used in your local development for debugging.

Comment: I have this problem and the file is set to "chmod 777 file.txt", and also set "chown daemon file.txt".

Answer (score 2):

By default when XAMPP is installed, the htdocs folder does not have any read permissions. You can change the permissions through the terminal like this.

```
cd /Application/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test/
sudo chmod 0664 file.txt
```

Alternatively, you can recursively set all the permission level of all files and folders

```
cd /Application/XAMPP/xamppfiles/
sudo chmod -R 0664 htdocs/
```

Comment: I tried cd /Application/XAMPP/xamppfiles/
chmod -R 0664 htdocs/  but when I reloaded the page, the following error appeared: 

Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 403

localhost
Fri Aug 9 14:56:20 2013
Apache/2.2.14 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l PHP/5.3.1 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1

Comment: It seems that you are not the owner of these files. If that is the case, replace 664 with 777.

Comment: Using 777 is pretty much always a terrible idea.

Comment: Why is that? Even if the problem was resolved? Will it effect me in the future?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Ideally, you want 664, or 744 if you know what it means and how it affects the files.

Comment: Or you want to use ACLs.

Comment: @SomaMizobuchi Yes, it leaves you more vulnerable to being hacked. I highly recommend finding the actual cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could `chmod` to `777`, but that is risky security. What I'm guessing you really want is change ownership of the file. You can do this using `chown`. PHP usually runs as user `www-data`, so you'd run a command something like this.

`sudo chown www-data:root path/to/file.ext`

If you're file permission on the file was something normal like `664`, that'd give PHP the 6 permission (Read and Write) instead of the 4 (just Read).